# How to get query details FROM Webmaster tools API in PHP

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-search-console, google-api-webmasters

the new api webmasters tools is not mentioned how to get the details of queries in php.

Here is my code to get the queries, but I dont know how to get for each query the details :

```
<?php
require_once ('google-api-php-client-2.2.2/vendor/autoload.php');

$client->setAccessToken("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$webmastersService = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
$searchanalytics = $webmastersService->searchanalytics;


// Build query
$request = new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest;
$request->setStartDate('startdate');
$request->setEndDate('enddate');
$request->setDimensions("query");
$request->setSearchType("web");
$request->setRowLimit(10);
$qsearch = $searchanalytics->query("siteurl", $request); 
$rows = $qsearch->getRows();

var_dump($rows);
?>
```

But our code was not working.

what is the issue in our code?

Appreciate any help and ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> But our code was not working.
>
> what is the issue in our code?

I am not authorized to post comment under your topic, so I post here on Answer.
You should post the detail about "not working".Error messages or logs would be OK.

And should be
$targetSites = $webmastersService->sites->listSites()->siteEntry;
$qsearch = $searchanalytics->query($targetSite->siteUrl, $request);

I also doubt that 'startdate' and 'enddate', not conclete values, work.